# How to replace one column data with next column data in oracle sql?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, sql-update

I have one table having 4 columns and I want to replace the second column data with the third one?

e.g

```
Table1
       Title_ID   |     Title     |    Detail          |  Comments  |  
          1              HR          HR Manager             NULL
          2              IT          IT Manager             NULL
          3              FIN       Finance Supervisor       NULL
```

expected output :

Table1

```
   Title_ID   |    Title      |    Detail          |  Comments  |  
      1         HR Manager          HR                  NULL
      2          IT Manager         IT                  NULL
      3        Finance Supervisor  FIN                  NULL
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update or just select?

If former, then

```
update table1 set
  title  = detail,
  detail = title;
```

If latter,

```
select title_id, 
       detail as title, 
       title  as detail, 
       comments
from table1
```

Comment: Update. Not select

Comment: OK, that's the first code I posted, then.